# RecyclerView - Always scrolls back to top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a simple RecyclerView which has a LinearLayoutManager (VERTICAL). I am currently getting scrolled always back to the top of the list whenever I scroll downwards but only on Android 4.4.2 and lower. I faced the issue on two of six devices that I tested all running Android OS 4.4.2 and lower.

- Samsung Galaxy 10.1" Tab 2 GT-P5100 running OS version 4.4.2.
- And another custom made tab running Android OS 4.1.1.

I have other devices running OS versions >= .4.4.4 and they are working fine.

**UPDATE** : I should have mentioned this earlier, I also have other `RecyclerViews` (All HORIZONTAL) in my app and they are all working fine.